# Using underscore for subscript in text mode using underscore only

Tags: subscripts, text-mode, underscore

I want to use subscripts without actually being in math mode.

N_A is Avogadro constant
      instead of 
$N_A$ is Avogadro constant

Is there any method I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A mathematical constant should be typed in as math.

Answer (score 3):

the solution `N\textsubscript{A}` would produce the desired result.

However, you should note, that text-mode uses upright letters while math-mode writes letters in italics. I furthermore agree with @egreg, that

> mathematical constant should be typed in as math @egreg

Code: `N\textsubscript{A}` and `$N_A$`

[image]

Maybe helpful for you would be setting a new command to avoid having to repeatedly enter math mode for example:

`\newcommand{\avogadro}{N\textsubscript{A}}`or `\newcommand{\avogadro}{$N_A$}` would help.

Then you simply have to type:

`\avogadro{} %(the brackets are here to force a spacing after the constant)`

at any point to get the desired outcome. Most Front-End Programmes (like Texmaker) have auto-completion which comes in handy here.

Comment: My original question was to avoid repeatedly typing the same thing over and over again, the dollar signs in this case. I want a method where I only use the underscore (or another symbol) to automatically type a subscript. For example: N_A

Comment: @AbdelbakiZ If I now understood right, you want to redefine the _ (underscore) Symbol. I don't know how to do that unfortunately (and not sure whether it is possible), but hope my answer was of some help anyway.

Maybe somebody else an help :)